# xslt list output contains extra line breaks

Tags: xml, xslt, html-lists

I have an xslt code to display an XML file as tree view. The problem is that there are extra line breaks in the generated html list. I added normalize-space to remove extra lines but still there are extra line breaks left. Here is the xslt code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <li>&lt;!--<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>--&gt;</li>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="comment()[contains(., 'inline-figure')]">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <li><span>
      <xsl:if test="*">
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:value-of select="'caret caret-down'"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name())"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', name(), '=', '&quot;', ., '&quot;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="text() or *">
            <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'/&gt;'"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose></span>
      <xsl:if test="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="*">
        <ul class="nested active"><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="text() or *">
        <span><xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;','/' ,name() , '&gt;')"/></span>
      </xsl:if></li>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*/text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Here is the current output:

```
<xmp id="example">
<ul><li>
<span class="caret caret-down">&lt;catalog&gt;</span><ul class="nested active"><li>
<span class="caret caret-down">&lt;book id="bk101"&gt;</span><ul class="nested active">
<li>
<span>&lt;author&gt;</span>Gambardella, Matthew<span>&lt;/author&gt;</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>&lt;title&gt;</span>XML Developer's Guide<span>&lt;/title&gt;</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>&lt;genre&gt;</span>Computer<span>&lt;/genre&gt;</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>&lt;price&gt;</span>44.95<span>&lt;/price&gt;</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>&lt;publish_date&gt;</span>2000-10-01<span>&lt;/publish_date&gt;</span>
</li>
<li>
<span>&lt;description&gt;</span>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.<span>&lt;/description&gt;</span>
</li>
</ul>
<span>&lt;/book&gt;</span>
</li></ul>
<span>&lt;/catalog&gt;</span>
</li></ul></xmp>
```

and here is the css i used:

```
ul {
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

li { 
    display: inline;
}

.caret {
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none;
}

    .caret::before {
        content: "\25B6";
        color: black;
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

.caret-down::before {
    display: inline;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
}

.nested {
    display: none;
}

.active {
    display: block;
}
```

The output looks like this:
[extra line breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUaRj.png)

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible example: 
(1) Input XML 
(2) Your logic, and XSLT you tried to implement it. 
(3) Desired output.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I added more details.

Answer (score 0):

I modified just one single line in the XSLT. Everything else stays the same. Please try it.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

Browser output without CSS
[image: Edge output]

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Comment: I think I got it. I put the generated xml inside a <pre> tag or <xmp> tag. Which caused the extra line breaks. I removed the <pre> tag and it is working fine. Thanks.